# MongoDB doesn't save correctly passed data with $ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I am struggling with understanding what causes my script(s) to not add data that I send with ajax request. Instead of data that I pass it adds `" "` (obviously because it cannot parse the body for some reason)

What may cause this problem?

**Server side:**

```
router.post('/v2', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const person = new Person({
        firstName: req.body.firstName || ' ',
        secondName: req.body.secondName || ' '
    })
    try {
        const newPerson = await person.save()
        res.status(201).json({ message: { id: newPerson._id } })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: error.message })
    }
})
```

**Ajax request:**

```
function addUserToDB(data) {
    const promisedResponse = v2Request(data);
    promisedResponse.done(function (data) {
        console.log(data.message.id)
    });
    

    function v2Request(data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
              },
            url: "URL/v2",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
    
}
```

Code works fine as it returns correct response, but still with `" "` data added to db.
[image]

What's the problem?

Thanks ahead!

P.S. data -> Object generated by class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

**Server Side:**

```
router.post('/v2', async (req, res) => {
    
    if (!req.body) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Data not found" })
        return;
    }

    console.log(req.body)

    const person = new Person({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        secondName: req.body.secondName
    })

    try {
        await person.save()
        res.status(201).json({ message: "Data stored successfully" })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" })
    }
})
```

**Ajax Request**

```
function addUserToDB() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'URL/v2',
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },

        data: { firstName, secondName },

        success: function (result, stat, xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.responseJSON)
        },

        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            console.log(xhr.responseJSON)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem to be:

```
headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
},

data: JSON.stringify(data)
```